# Hosto set specific css to one widget in pygtk3?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

Have a `Gtk.Box()` and need add specific css only to widget. Have a dinamic class as Box called `CustomBox` and have functions like `setBackgroundColor(self, strRgbColor)`, need in each function modify the css only for that widget.

Example:

```
box1 = CustomBox()
box1.setPadding(10,10,0,0)

box2 = CustomBox()
box2.setBackgroundColor('#ff0000')
```

Need each widget with specific css.

Y have:

```
self.id = 'box_' + str(id(self))
box = Gtk.Box()
box.set_name(self.id)
# ...
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_data(('#' + self.id + '{ border: 1px solid red; }').encode())
context = Gtk.StyleContext()
# ... ??
```

Where `self.id` is the unique id (with `id(self)`), but how set the css_provider to `box`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`context.add_provider()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider) to affect only the widget itself (not its children nor any other widgets) or [`Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen) to affect all created widgets in your program.